# How to create a hash that in incognito mode stays the same even after browser refreshs with fingerprintjs2?

Tags: javascript, incognito-mode, fingerprintjs2

Is there a way to make a unique hash code that fingerprintjs2 generates to be the same in incognito mode even after refreshs?

This is my code, maybe there is a mistake in the code?

```
 const Fingerprint2 = require("fingerprintjs2");

 var options = {}
 if (window.requestIdleCallback) {
 requestIdleCallback(function () {
    Fingerprint2.get(function (components) {
        console.log(components) // an array of components: {key: ..., value: ...}
    })
})
} else {
setTimeout(function () {
    Fingerprint2.get(function (components) {
        console.log(components) // an array of components: {key: ..., value: ...}
    })
}, 500)
}

Fingerprint2.get(options, function (components) {
var values = components.map(function (component) { return component.value })
var murmur = Fingerprint2.x64hash128(values.join(''), 31)

console.log(murmur) // provides a hash
})
```

The problem is, that in normal browsing mode the hash stay's the same, but in incognito mode, it changes after refresing and e.t.c

I would be content if in incognito mode the hash would'nt change, even if it would be diffirenet then in normal browsing mode.

Thanks for the help, i'm not an expert in javascript, any help provided will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

in options you can set `doNotTrack` to false

```js
Fingerprint2.getV18({
    excludes: {
        doNotTrack: false
    }
}, (murmur, components) => {
    // murmur => your calculated hash
})
```